# Regex replace in Android Studio to UPPERCASE

Tags: regex, android-studio, uppercase, regexp-replace

Does anyone know if it is possible to perform a Regular Expression replace operation in AndroidStudio where a particular match can be converted to uppercase?

Example:

I want to search find all occurrences of;

```
Log.i
Log.e
Log.d
```

...and replace them with :

```
if ( LogConfig.LOGI ) Log.i
if ( LogConfig.LOGE ) Log.e
if ( LogConfig.LOGD ) Log.d
```

In other words, some of the replacements are as is (no brainer) but others must be **CAPITALIZED**.

If this is possible, how do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried at least something? What works and what does not?

Comment: @Wiktor All I know if that by matching the occurrence of one 'match' with wildcards (e.g. $1), I can repeat the match.  I've looked everywhere for uppercase substitution and found nothing.  So replacing 'Log\.[ied]' with 'if ( LogConfig.LOG$1 ) Log.$1' will not give me what I'm looking for because I cannot find how to ask AndroidStudio to replace $1 with UPPERCASE($1)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/YNnt0A/1, `(Log)\.([ied])` => `if ( LogConfig.\U$1$2\E ) $0`

Comment: Wiktor, you are a genius.  I did not know we could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(Log)\.([ied])
```

Replace with `if ( LogConfig.\U$1$2\E ) $0`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNnt0A/1).

If you need to match `Log.e` as a whole word, add word boundaries, `\b(Log)\.([ied])\b`.

**Details**

- `(Log)` - Capturing group 1: `Log`
- `\.` - a dot
- `([ied])` - a letter `i`, `e` or `d`.

The `\U$1$2\E` means:

- `\U` - start turning to upper case all that follows:

  - `$1` - Group 1 value
  - `$2` - Group 2 value
- `\E` - stop turning to uppercase.